# How to add custom soup message headers in gjs?

Tags: gjs, libsoup

I can't find any method in `Soup.Message` that would allow me to add custom headers. I tried adding headers using `Message.requset_headers` but that field is read only. How can I add custom header to my message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Message.request_headers`](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/soup24%7E2.74.2/soup.message#property-request_headers) is read-only, but its value is a [Soup.MessageHeaders](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/soup24%7E2.74.2/soup.messageheaders) instance, which has an [append()](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/soup24%7E2.74.2/soup.messageheaders#method-append) method you can use to add a custom header.